# Graph theory analysis

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image: Graph]

Hi! I need help with verifying this exercise and clarifying a doubt. I might tell you the definition I have since I'm translating and I don't know if with the translation I get the same terms in English.

The exercise says:

**a. Find all the proper paths (paths) that go from vertex A to vertex F.**

Proper path - is when all vertices are different. Every proper path is a simple path.

So this is what I got: ${(A,B,C,F), (A,B,C,E,F), (A,B,E,F), (A,B,E,C,F),  (A,D,E,F), (A,D,E,C,F), (A,D,E,B,C,F)}$

**b. Find all the simple paths (trails) that go from A to F.**

Simple path (trail) - is when all the arcs are different.

${(A,B,C,F), (A,B,C,E,F), (A,B,E,F), (A,B,E,C,F), (A,D,E,F), (A,D,E,C,F), (A,D,E,B,C,F), (A,D,E,B,C,E,F)}$

**c. Find the distance from A to F.**

Distance - the shortest length between two vertices.

So the distance is 3.

**d. The diameter of the graph.**

Diameter - the maximum of the distance between the vertices of the graph.

So diameter is 5.

**e. Find the subgraphs obtained by removing each of its vertices. Are there cut points in that graph (a cut point in a connected graph is that one that when eliminated, together with all its incident edges, gives rise to a not connected graph)?**

**EDITED:** Are these all?

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It looks to me like the diameter is $3$, not $5$.

Comment: @RobertShore The definition of diameter is the maximum eccentricity of any vertex in the graph. That is, it is the greatest distance between any pair of vertices. I get the path $(A,D,E,B,C,F)$, the distance is 5. I think that is the maximum.

Comment: @gi2302, however, the distance is defined as the length of the shortest path between two vertices. $(A, D, E, B, C, F)$ is not the shortest path between $A$ and $F$.

Comment: @Fullfungo but the premise says the distance between vertices $A$ and $F$. I guess if it was just the distance of the graph was $1$, but since is from $A$ to $F$, I determined it was $3$ since it is the shortest.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments it looks like you got a bit confused for the definitions of diameter and distance.

The **diameter** is **not** the maximum path length between any two vertices. The diameter of the graph is the maximum **distance** between any two vertices. And the distance between two vertices is the length of the **shortest** path.

Given the shortest path $ABCF$, the distance between $A$ and $F$ is 3, and this is fixed. Even if there exist longer paths such as $ADEBCF$, the distance is still 3. We can reach $F$ from $A$ in 3 steps. Therefore the eccentricity of $A$ is $3$, not $5$.

The diameter is a max/min value. If $V$ is our set $\{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$
$$ diam = \max_{x,y\in V} \{distance(x,y)\}$$
$$ diam = \max_{x,y\in V} \{\min_{path(x\to y) }length(path)\}$$

The distance between $A$ and $F$ is fixed at 3, so we know that $diam\geq 3$. In order to find the diameter of the graph, you need to check the distance between all other pairs of vertices. It is easy to see that for any other pair of vertices the distance is less than 3. Therefore
$$diam = 3$$

Regarding the last question : when you remove a vertex, you remove all the edges that "end" at this vertex (we say all edges *incident* with this vertex). For example if you remove the vertex $A$, you get the following subgraph.

[image]

I'm sure you can finish from here.

Comment: thanks for helping me understand this. I got it now the diameter meaning. I edited the original question on the last premise because I couldn't post pictures here.  Are all of them the subgraphs? There are not cut points, right? Since all of them are connected.

Comment: Your last question is correct, these are the subgraphs and there are no cut points